# Creating a view with LEFT and INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, left-join, inner-join

I have a question about creating a view here. I came up with a quick example to illustrate the issue.

- Contracts have Headers and Line Items.
- Contract Headers as well as Line Items have both different statuses from different tables and ARE required (not null)
- ContactID is not required for Contract Header

See tables below:

```
[Contacts]
PK.ContactID
ContactName

[ContractHeader]
PK.ContractID
ContractThruDate
FK.ContactID
FK.ContractStatusID (REQUIRED)

[ContractStatus]
PK.ContractStatusID
ContractStatusName

[ContractLineItem]
PK.ContractLineItemID
ContractLineItemDate
ContractLineItemName
FK.ContractLineItemStatusID (REQUIRED)
FK.ContractID

[ContractLineItemStatus]
PK.ContractLineItemStatusID
ContractLineItemStatusName
```

Now if I want to create a full view of this, I would do:

```
SELECT *
FROM ContractHeader CH
   INNER JOIN ContractStatus CS ON CH.ContractStatusID = CS.ContractStatusID
   LEFT JOIN Contacts CON ON CH.ContactID = CON.ContactID
   LEFT JOIN ContractLineItem CLI ON CLI.ContractID = CH.ContractID
   ...
```

So far I have Contacts, ContractHeader, ContractStatuses and ContractLineItems, so I could easily add

```
   ...
   LEFT JOIN ContractLineItemStatus CLIS ON CLI.ContractLineItemStatusID = CLIS.ContractLineStatusID
```

But since a ContractLineItemStatus is required when the ContractLineItem is joined, I would want to INNER JOIN the ContractLineStatus within the LEFT JOIN of ContractLineItem.

Is that possible? Or do I have to continue doing LEFT JOIN on everything once the parent has been LEFT JOIN-ed in the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this link answers your question: http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/10/11/mixing-inner-outer-joins-sql.aspx

In summary:

- left join are followed by left join...
- ... which might result in a "loss" of information in which case you might need to handle it with a subquery.

For your example case:

```
SELECT *
FROM ContractHeader CH
    INNER JOIN ContractStatus CS ON CH.ContractStatusID = CS.ContractStatusID
    LEFT JOIN Contacts CON ON CH.ContactID = CON.ContactID
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT * FROM ContractLineItem CLI
        INNER JOIN ContractLineItemStatus CLIS ON CLI.ContractLineItemStatusID = CLIS.ContractLineStatusID
    ) AS CLI_AND_S ON CH.ContractID = CLI_AND_S.ContractID
```

So to answer your question: no, if you use an inner join after your left join, you will lose the ContractHeader that have no ContractLineItem. Yo can preserve the inner join between ContractLineItem and ContractLineItemStatus by using a subquery.

EDIT: replaced the previous query which should not have worked

Answer (score 0):

If you put an `INNER JOIN` between ContractLineItem and ContractLineItemStatus tables if there aren't ContractLineItem about one ContractStatus you'll cut those ContractStatus lines. So if your initial goal was view all ContractStatus, with or without other informations, you can't apply an `INNER JOIN` between those two tables.

Comment: Thought I misread so I removed the comment, then I realized I didn't ^^

The initial goal is to view all Contracts with their Header and LineItem information, and of course, their statuses. All ContractLineItems as well as ContractHeaders have statuses, so INNER JOIN would work on Contract for 100%, but if I use INNER JOIN between ContractLineItem and ContractLineItemStatus, I lose all the records as soon as a ContractHeader don't have a ContractLineItem

Comment: @IvanM: you write:  if I use INNER JOIN between ContractLineItem and ContractLineItemStatus, I lose all the records as soon as a ContractHeader don't have a ContractLineItem. I say: Exact. So if you don't want to lose those rows, you can't use INNER JOIN. Otherwise yes. ;)